# How to create properly disjunct @media queries in a cross-compatible way?

Tags: css, media-queries

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="x">A</div>
```

And say I want to apply the following styling rules to it:

- If the screen width is 600px or more, I want to apply a box shadow.
- If the screen width is any less than 600px, I want to apply a solid border.

My intuition was to write queries like so:

```css
@media (min-width: 600px)
{
    #x { box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px green; }
}
@media not (min-width: 600px)
{
    #x { border: solid 1px #666; }
}
```

```html
<div id="x">A</div>
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari, the `not` query is never applied.

I can think of three other options:

1. `@media (max-width: 599px)`
   This has a chance of applying *neither* style if the browser zoom level isn't 100%, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19197).
2. `@media (max-width: 600px)`
   This is *guaranteed* to apply both queries when the window width is exactly 600px.
3. Dumping one of the styles in the default ruleset and "undoing" everything it does manually with `<attribute>: default` everywhere.
   This is simply not practical.

Is there any way I can accomplish the above without missing edge cases?

I feel like this would have been asked before, but you can't Google for `not` queries because all you'll find is "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDN docs:

> Note: In most cases, the all media type is used by default when no other type is specified. However, if you use the not or only operators, you must explicitly specify a media type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Chrome/Safari seem to like it better if you add an "all" media type after the "not"

```css
@media (min-width: 600px)
{
    #x { box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px green; }
}
@media not all and (min-width: 600px)
{
    #x { border: solid 1px #666; }
}
```

```html
<div id="x">A</div>
```